# Біля чи близько?

Tags: вживання-слів, вибір-слова

У новинах ми часто чуємо повідомлення про аварії та катастрофи, де ведучий вживає такі фрази: " ***біля*** 100 жертв" чи "***близько*** 100 жертв". Донедавна думала, що обидва ці вирази правильні. Але наткнулась у [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%8F:%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%83_%D0%B7_%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%96%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97) на думку, що вираз "***біля*** 100 жертв" є неправильним. Хоча у тлумачному словнику і [***біля***](http://sum.in.ua/s/bilja), і [***близько***](http://sum.in.ua/s/blyzjko) означені як такі, що вживаються для позначення приблизної кількості. То ж як правильно вживати ці слова?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У сучасному [Словнику української мови](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=4456&page=166) подають таку інформацію:

> **БІ́ЛЯ**, прийм., з род. в.1. Уживається на позначення місця; коло, **близько**, недалеко.
>
> Ти знаєш.. Чого Еней приплив к Латину І біля моря поселивсь (І. Котляревський)
>
> *УВАГА!* 2. *розм*. **Уживається на позначення приблизної кількості; близько**.
>
> Біля сотні озброєних мисливців-старовірів товпиться коло тайгової дзвіниці
>   (О. Довженко).

[Офіційний сайт Української мови](https://ukrainskamova.com/publ/chinnij_pravopis/morfologija_i_pravopis/osoblivosti_vzhivannja_dejakikh_prijmennikiv/6-1-0-147) подає цікаву доволі інформацію:

> Іноді сплутують значення прийменників **біля** та **близько**.
>
> Прийменник ***біля + родовий відмінок*** = позначення ***місця***:
>   Дніпра, біля будинків, біля станції метро. На місце можуть вказувати ще прийменники близько та коло: близько Києва, коло хати.
>
> Але для позначення ***приблизної кількості***  вживаються тіль­ки прийменники ***близько*** та ***коло***: близько (коло) десятої години, близько (коло) тридцяти днів, близько одного кілометра. А вислови на зразок *«біля п'ятої години», «біля двох кілограмів»  не відповідають літературній нормі.*

Отже, прийменники біля та близько як взаємозамінні при будь-яких конструкціях, зокрема наведених Вами можна використовувати, проте лише у розмовному стилі, якщо ж говорити про літературну мову, зокрема науковий, офіційно-діловий стиль тощо, то краще дотримуватись тієї інформації, що зазначена на [Офіційному сайті Української мови](https://ukrainskamova.com/publ/chinnij_pravopis/morfologija_i_pravopis/osoblivosti_vzhivannja_dejakikh_prijmennikiv/6-1-0-147).

Comment: Підступно користуючись посадовим становищем, зауважую, що мені здалося, що ви рідко голосуєте за запитання і відповіді.
Репутаційні бали — другий за важливістю наріжний камінь діяльності Stack Exchange (другий після якісних матеріалів).
Тому закликаю вас не нехтувати голосуванням. [**Голосуйте одразу та багато!**](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/17/)

Comment: добре, частіше голосуватиму)